# QT MySql database checking login and password to sign in

Tags: c++, mysql, database, qt, qt5

I want to make app in qt in which will be login and register system, logins and passwords are in the MySQL database. I've connected database to my app but i dont know how to compare logins and passwords with given in "line edit" this is code from tutorial but it is tutorial to SQLite

```
void login::on_pushButton_sign_in_clicked()

QString login, password;
login = ui->lineEdit_login_login->text();
password = ui->lineEdit_password_login->text();

QSqlQuery qry;

if(qry.exec("select logins, passwords * from users where logins =  '" + login + "' and password = '" + password + "' " ))
{
    while(qry.next())
    {
        hide();
        mainwindow = new MainWindow(this);
        mainwindow->show();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: What is "passwords *"

Comment: "passwords" it is a name of column where are passwords of users

Comment: That code looks like an SQL-Injection (Users can delete your database using SQL code as username). You should **NEVER** simply concatenate use input into a query string! Use bind values instead!

Comment: @Felix could You give me example how to use that?

Comment: I already updated the reply of @Bobur - there you can see it in action. Basically you use placeholders in the SQL query and use `prepare` instead of `exec`, then set the values via `bindValue` and finally call `exec` without any parameters

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in the comments, you should first learn about basic SQL queries. Let's say you have a `users` table and it has columns as below:

`| userId  | name | username | password |`

Having `myUsername` and `myPassword` from your custom app, your SQL query might look like this:

`SELECT userID, name from users WHERE username = 'myUsername' AND password = 'myPassword'`

Now, you use it in your code:

```
void login::on_pushButton_sign_in_clicked()
{
    QString username = ui->lineEdit_login_login->text();
    QString password = ui->lineEdit_password_login->text();

    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("SELECT userID, name from users WHERE 
                    username = :username AND 
                    password = :password");
    query.bindValue(":username", username);
    query.bindValue(":password", password);
    if (query.exec())
    {
        if (query.size() > 0)
        {
            // You login a user here
            QString name = query.value(1).toString();
            qDebug() << name << "is logged in";
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Login failed. Invalid username or password.";
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I assume it is for learning purpose. Its recommended to store password [hash](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) rather than plain text. Cheers!

Comment: Still not working, when i push button even qdebug not showing that username or password is invalid

Comment: what is your table name? what are the names of columns? You should change name in the query to fit your table and column names. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes i changed :(

Comment: then it's probably because query is not executed properly. `if (query.exec(...))` is returning false. Before executing query, check if you are connected to your DB: `if (db.isOpen()) { // execute query }` where `db` is an instance of `QSqlDatabase`.

Comment: I've add this  if(db.isOpen())
                    qDebug() << "open";
and when i click button to sign in it shows that db is open

Comment: Could you execute this query on db console or agent itself? So you would see the actual result of query.

Comment: Be aware of the edits I made - you should *always* use bound values to add user inputs to queries for proper escaping